# Download file with angular 5 and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, angular5

I'm trying to download a file from a specific directory everything works fine in the back-end when I test the service, but when I try it from the front-end I get this error and the pop/up save doesn't show.
Here's my back-end code with spring boot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnc1V.png)

and my front with angular 5 looks like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abxR7.png)

the service :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQyX9.png)

Answer (score 1):

After your

```
respHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
```

Try adding this:

```
respHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"");
```